# QTQuick 5.7 how to change QML Object Property from C++

Tags: c++, qtquick

Доброго времени суток! Не могу решить проблему:

разрабатываю меню на QTQuick 5.7
Есть несколько QML форм: main.qml, Page.qml, Options.qml...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть кнопка в main.qml:

```
Button {
    id: button1
    x: 178
    y: 227
    text: qsTr("PressMe")

    onClicked: {
        button1.text = "Clicked"

        var result = testclasses.getSomeProperty()
    }
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку вызывается некая функция **testclasses.*getSomeProperty()***

Класс с этой функцией определен в main.h:

```
class TestClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void getSomeProperty();
};
```

Метод реализуется так:

```
        void TestClass::getSomeProperty()
        {
            qDebug() << "Event is here";

            QQuickView view;

            view.setSource(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/Page1Form.ui.qml")) );
            view.show();
            QObject *object = view.rootObject();

            QObject *txttxt = object->findChild<QObject*>("texttochange");
            if (txttxt){

                qDebug() << txttxt->property("text");


                txttxt->setProperty("text", "текст изменен");

                qDebug() << txttxt->property("text");
            }
        }
```

Экземпляр класса создается в Main:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
        QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

        QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

        QQmlContext* context = engine.rootContext();

        TestClass tc;

        context->setContextProperty("testclasses", &tc);

        engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

        app.exec();
    }
```

Делал по примерам с интернета. В итоге при нажатии бесконечного числа раз на кнопку лог выводится таким образом

> Debug\debug\Memograph.exe...
>   QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment. Event
>   is here QVariant(QString, "Начальная страница") QVariant(QString,
>   "текст изменен") Event is here QVariant(QString, "Начальная страница")
>   QVariant(QString, "текст изменен") Event is here QVariant(QString,
>   "Начальная страница") QVariant(QString, "текст изменен")

То есть у нас текст как будто бы меняется, но по факту ничего не меняется.
Подскажите, как все-таки корректно изменять аттрибуты qml форм из кода C++.
С ООП работаю очень недавно, даётся всё тяжело, но делать надо.

Answer (score 0):

исправил, заработало:

myclass.h:

```
        #ifndef MYCLASS_H
        #define MYCLASS_H

        #include <QObject>
        #include <QDebug>

        class MyClass : public QObject
        {
            Q_OBJECT
        public:
            MyClass(QObject *QMLObject) : viewer(QMLObject) {}

        signals:

        public slots:
            void buttonClicked(const QString& in);
        protected:
            QObject *viewer;
        };

        #endif // MYCLASS_H
```

main.cpp

```
        #include <QGuiApplication>
        #include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

        #include <QQmlContext>
        #include "myclass.h"

        int main(int argc, char *argv[])
        {
            QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

            QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
            engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

            QObject* root = engine.rootObjects()[0];
            MyClass myClass(root);
            engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("_myClass", &myClass);

            return app.exec();
        }
```

myclass.cpp

```
        #include "myclass.h"

        void MyClass::buttonClicked(const QString& in)
        {
            qDebug() << in;//Просто выведем информацию строки in в консоль Debug. Просто так.

        //    //Найдем строки ввода
                QObject* textinput1 = viewer->findChild<QObject*>("inptext");
                QString str1=(textinput1->property("text")).toString();
                qDebug() << str1;
                textinput1->setProperty("text", "Yeah");

                ////////************

                QObject* rect = viewer->findChild<QObject*>("rectcolortochange");
                QString str12=(rect->property("width")).toString();
                qDebug() << str12;
                rect->setProperty("width", 100);
        }
```

ну а для того чтобы вызвать это событие, например, на обработчик нажатия кнопки, делаю так

```
        import QtQuick 2.4

        OptionsFormForm {
            button1.onClicked: {
                _myClass.buttonClicked("Worked?")
        }
        }
```

Вот так уже не первый раз в жизни - стоит озвучить вопрос, так находится на него ответ, хотя маялся два дня

Comment: причем, свойства можно менять у любой формы в проекте, лишь бы был аттрибут objectName